# to rotate the motor when signal is received from bluetooth and stop the motor when button is pressed

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-ide

I am using Bluetooth HC-O5, push button, Arduino Nano and DC motor of 40rpm. I'll first explain my question. 
(Case 1)I want to start rotating the motor when it receives the signal from bluetooth and stop the motor rotation when the push button is pushed.
(Case 2) I want to start rotating the motor when button is pushed and it receives signal from bluetooth and stop the rotation when button is pressed.

Now I did the coding using Arduino IDE in which Case 1 works well in Case 2 the motor rotates and stops without pushing the button.
My code is below.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(10,6);
const int  buttonPin = 3;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int  motorPin = 9;
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;       // the pin that the LED is attached to


int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int currentState = 0;
int lastState = 0;
int Data;
int c_lastState = 0;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  Serial.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  delay(1000);
  Bluetooth.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  Serial.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
  // read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Bluetooth.available();  
  Data=Bluetooth.read(); 
    if(Data=='1'){
      Serial.println("Motor rotating");
      digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
      currentState = buttonState;
      lastState = 0; 
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      Serial.print("Button State - ");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Current Button State - ");
      Serial.println(currentState);
      Serial.print("Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(lastState);
     // lastState == 0;
      //Serial.print("Changed Last Button State - ");
      //Serial.println(lastState);
    }

    else if (buttonState == 1 and lastState == 0){
      Serial.println("Motor Stop");
      digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
      currentState = buttonState;
      lastState = currentState; 
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Button State - ");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Current Button State - ");
      Serial.println(currentState);
      Serial.print("Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(lastState);
    }


    if(Data=='1' and buttonState == 1){
      Serial.println("Motor rotating..............................");
      digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
      currentState = buttonState;
      lastState = currentState; 
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      Serial.print("Button State - ");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Current Button State - ");
      Serial.println(currentState);
      Serial.print("Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(lastState);
      c_lastState = 1;
      Serial.print("Changed Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(c_lastState);
    }


    else if (buttonState == 1 and c_lastState == 0){
      Serial.println("Motor Stop");
      digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
      currentState = buttonState;
      lastState = currentState; 
      c_lastState = lastState;
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Button State - ");
      Serial.println(buttonState);
      Serial.print("Current Button State - ");
      Serial.println(currentState);
      Serial.print("Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(lastState);
      Serial.print("Changed Last Button State - ");
      Serial.println(c_lastState);
    }
}
```

Here due to the variable used is creating a problem but without using I am not able to solve the Case 1 so I have used it. if any one has any other way to solve please let me know.

Comment: In both case you want to use the same button or different?

Comment: @Pradeep yes same button to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for starting and stopping the motor with bluetooth as well as button(start or stop only when change in data or button to HIGH occurs).

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(10,6);
const int  buttonPin = 3;    // the pin that the pushbutton is attached to
const int  motorPin = 9;
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;       // the pin that the LED is attached to


int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int running=0;
int lastState = 0;
int data=0;
int lastData=0;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Bluetooth.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  Serial.println("Send 1 to open LOCK. Send 0 to close LOCK");
  delay(1000);
  Bluetooth.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  Serial.println("Waiting for command..."); 
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {

    // start and stop with bluetooth when data changed to 1
  Bluetooth.available();  
// read the data:
  data = Bluetooth.read();

  // compare the data to its previous state
  if (data != lastData) {
    // the state has changed
    if (data == 1) {
      // if the current state is 1 
      if(running)
      {
          //stop if running already
          Serial.println("Motor Stop");
          digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
          running = 0;
      }
        else
        {
            //start if not running
            Serial.println("Motor start");
          digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
            running = 1;
        }
    } 

    // Delay to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
  // save the current state as the last state
 lastData = data;

// start and stop with pushbutton when it changed to HIGH

// read the pushbutton input pin:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  // compare the buttonState to its previous state
  if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
    // the state has changed
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
      // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
      if(running)
      {
          Serial.println("Motor Stop");
          digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
          running = 0;
      }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Motor start");
          digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
            running = 1;
        }
    } 

    // Delay to avoid bouncing
    delay(50);
  }
  // save the current state as the last state
 lastButtonState = buttonState;

}
```